# Cannot resolve symbol appCompatActivity on create of new project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Project Level Gradle file:Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

module level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.co.persistent.gamedisappear"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

`
[image: The error I get]I know this question is asked many times.But I have tried various things like invalidate/restart cache.Also tried restarting android and building new project.Plus added the required dependencies (compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1') Nothing works!

Comment: Please post your error codes and gradle properties for your app :)

Comment: I have attached the image of the error I get!

Comment: Will you post your build.gradle file please?

Comment: And please note that this has nothing to do with importing AppCompatActivity. Your gradle file is not syncing properly so everything will show as invalid.

Comment: show your `build.gradle` and do gradle until finish

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 I have posted the build.gradle file!

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have attached the Build.gradle file.

Comment: @Delfin Please gradle your project just

Comment: New to android @IntelliJAmiya can you elaborate on what to do.

Comment: @Delfin I'm not sure but some guys suggested to delete the gradle fodler and resync your project. Can u make a try keep a back up of that folder and delete and try once

Comment: @Delfin can u post your project level build.gradle once?

Comment: @Raghavendra I had tried that also through the suggestions of a previous similar question but it dint work out for me

Comment: @Delfin just to confirm can u post ur project level build.gradle?

Comment: Please try by using lower version for dependency only.

Comment: @Raghavendra I have already posted.

Comment: @ShadowDroid tried that too !

Comment: @Delfin no that is module level gradle I have asked another project level gradle file

Comment: @Delfin try ShadowDroid soln. and try mine too:) add this line repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
} and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the gradle build error screenshot it is clear that problem is **Could no resolve  junit:junit:4.12**
**Solution-** If you do not need to run unit test cases then you comment following line `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` and check 
but if you need it then please add following codes in module level build.gradle file

```
repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
```

**EDIT-** Reason based on question asked in comment.
**Why we get error?** Sometimes it might happen that required dependency/used version might not be present/path changed in the repository. For more information you need to understand how gradle works

Comment: Yes I had done the same and it worked, but why the error they are just dependencies after all.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my dependencies to below in build.gradle and it worked... Though don't know the reason behind this.

```
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add `com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.1` to your previous dependencies. Because in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html) it says `This library depends on the v4 Support Library.`